# Can you (automatically) limit the X axis range in a datetime plot in Power BI

Tags: datetime, powerbi, range, histogram, x-axis

In Microsoft Power BI I have data with a datetime field where I plot the data in a histogram like below:
[image: Power BI plot with datetime X-axis]
Y axis is count and X axis is a datetime field

Even though the data is only between Aug 21st and Sept 21 the graph X axis is Jan 1st to Dec 31st. Is there a way to limit the X axis, preferably automatically, to the data range.

Comment: You can create a Calendar table with `CALENDARAUTO()` and use it as X axis

Answer (score 0):

FYI, that's not a histogram. Why is it showing empty values? Are you returning zero instead of blank in your measure? If you need to keep things as they are,then just write a measure to calculate your min max and add it to the filter pane.

```
 Chart Min Max = 
    VAR chartMin = Calculate(MIN(fact_table[date]), REMOVEFILTERS('Date'))
    VAR chartMax = Calculate(MAX(fact_table[date]), REMOVEFILTERS('Date'))
    VAR result = IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date]) >= chartMin && SELECTEDVALUE('Date'[Date]) <= chartMax, 1) 

RETURN

result
```